# How to join two classes or print a class from the DOM

Tags: javascript, join, printing

I have a DOM with a class in it .printableArea. There are several divs on the page with the same class but they hold different information. What I need to do is print the contents of this class to have it combine the contents into a single printed page. Alternatively, I can rename the divs with unique ids (e.g., #printableArea1 and #printableArea2) and print the contents of these instead. By priny I mean actually print to a printer.

Can anybody possibly shed some light on printing the contents of classes or two or more ids together?

Will I need a concat of some sort?

```
\\This is the original that loads the contents of the first .printableArea. 
\\Changing the code to [1] instead of [0] gives the contents of the second .printableArea 

<input type="button" align="centre" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" 
value="Print Page" />
<script>
function printDiv(divName) {
 var printContents = document.getElementsByClassName(divName) 
 [0].innerHTML;
 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

 window.print();

 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
 }
 </script>

\\This also yields a result if I change to using an id instead of class.

<input type="button" align="centre" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" 
value="Print Page" />
<script>
function printDiv(divName) {
 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

 window.print();

 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
```

The expected result would be all the contents of the same class printing onto a single page or the contents of the different ids printing on a single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of all the elements matching the selector. You're only selecting a single element of the array with `[0]`. The solution is to iterate over the array and add each elements outer HTML to a variable and then replace the document body with that variable.

Im using outerHTML instead of inner because it includes the actual element itself and not just the children.

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
 var originalContents = document.body.outerHTML;
 
 // Initially set printContents to an empty string
 var printContents = '';
 
 // Get all the printable area elements
 var printableAreaEls = document.getElementsByClassName(divName);
 
 // Turn this into an array
 var printableAreaElsArray = Array.from(printableAreaEls);
 
 // Iterate over the array and add each elements outerHTML to the printContent variable (this is where the magic happens)
 printableAreaElsArray.forEach(function (printSegment) {
  printContents += '<br>' + printSegment.outerHTML;
 })

 document.body.outerHTML = printContents;
 window.print();
 document.body.outerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

```html
<div class="printableArea">Print this</div>
<div>But dont print this</div>
<div class="printableArea"><span>Also print this</span></div>
<button onclick="printDiv('printableArea')">Print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to apply Print Only styles, that is, CSS page styles that only apply when you're printing the page.

This is achievable by wrapping the print-only styles in the following media selector:

```
@media print {
  /* print-only styles here */
}
```

What you could do is hide all the elements that dont have the .printableArea class.

```
@media print {
  body :not(.printableArea) {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

But that will actually hide descendents of the .printableArea class, not ideal. We can select those descendents separately and reset their display property to their initial value.

```
@media print {
  body :not(.printableArea) {
    display: none !important;
  }

  body .printableArea * {
    display: initial !important;
  }
}
```

This means you can completely remove your JavaScript and change the Print Button to:

```
<input type="button" align="centre" onclick="window.print()" 
value="Print Page"/>
```

## Interactive Example

```css
@media print {
  body :not(.printableArea) {
    display: none !important;
  }

  body .printableArea * {
    display: initial !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="printableArea">Print this</div>
<div>But dont print this</div>
<div class="printableArea"><span>Also print this</span></div>
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```